# How to get location of comments from word file in c#

Tags: c#

I have tried Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. In that, I have tried Range property. But not getting a result.

```
Application application = new Application();
Document document = application.Documents.Open("D:\\Files\\Meeting Agenda.doc");
var commentRange = document.Comments[1].Range;
```

Comment: No screenshots of your code, please. Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulF do you getting the location of comments of word file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood exactly what you wanted.

It is the "Scope" property of the "Comment" object that you need - it is a range & you can obtain the location of the comment from that (Start/End are 0 based offset from start of document). So use :

```
var commentRange = document.Comments[1].Scope;
```

The "Range" property is the comment itself (Start/End properties appear to be offsets in a list of comments).

The documentation states the "Reference" property indicates the location of the comment but the Start and End properties are always 1 apart & seem to be the end of the comment & the Text property is always null.

Comment: I need the location of comments, where exactly comments located in doc file example: at 26th character means 26 is an index of that character where comment located. But in Scope and Range, I got "{System.__ComObject}" as a return value. So how it is helpful to me?

Comment: When working with Office Interop you are getting COM objects back rather than references to a class - but just like a class the COM objects have properties. Scope is also Range COM object & if you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.range?view=word-pia) you will see that it has Start & End properties giving the character offset from the start of the document.  It is very difficult to look at the properties through the debugger.

Comment: Thanks!  but I already checked that documentation and also tried Start and End properties but I m not getting what I want so that's why I have raised questions here. Even I have also tried : `var commentLine = document.Comments[1].Range.Information[WdInformation.wdFirstCharacterLineNumber];
            var commentRange = document.Comments[1].Range.Information[WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber];`

Comment: When I have examined a document then _"document.Comments[1].Scope.Start"_ has always shown to be the start offset of the comment in the document similarly _"document.Comments[1].Scope.End"_ is the end of the comment. _"document.Comments[1].Scope.Text"_ is the text that the comment is attached to & _"document.Comments[1].Range.Text"_ is the comment itself.

Comment: yes you are right, Thank you! The scope is helpful to me. As per suggested I got a start index.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer right as an aid to other users who may have the same problem.